# How to read files containing different formats/extensions?

Tags: c++, file, format

I am very new to c++ and I wanted to write a program that would read and extract data from files with/of different format (example: .dat). I just want to read and extract the data from it. Some people say something about file headers, structures and bodies, what are they actually ?

Comment: share some example code..

Comment: The extension `.dat` is *very* general, there's no specified format, but many different programs use many different formats. You could read the first X bytes to try and identify the format but there's no guarantee that it will be correct.

Comment: what about file headers, structures, bodies and stuff ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need a different strategy (code) for each file format.

A file with extension .txt usually contains ASCII data and is simple to read.

A file with extension .doc contains binary data for  MS Word and is virtually impossible to read with something other than MS Word.

All other file formats are somwhere inbetween these extremes.

The **file extension** will give you a hint about the files contents. Often people use the extension as a synonym for the actual **file format**. So we say "I have a .WAV file" when we actually mean "I have a binary file in RIFF/WAVE format with an .wav extension"

Some file formats (Like .WAV .MP3 .TIFF and so on) contain a (well documented) header which describes the file's structure in the first few bytes.

So **Header** means: The first few Bytes of a file which describe the contents/structure/layout of the file. For example in the first few bytes of a .WAV file you'll find number of channels, sampling rate, etc which explains how the rest of the file needs to be read in, interpreted and send to an audio device.

Some other popular extensions (like .dat .bin .hex) say not much more than "this is binary data in an unspecified format/structure." So you need (a lot of) additional information to read these files in a meaningful way.

[Wikipedia article about file extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions_%28alphabetical%29)

[Wikipedia article about file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats)

Comment: What exactly file headers are ?

Comment: As stated above, this depends on the exact file format. Formats with headers always define their own header structure. They are all different (and usually complicated)

Answer (score 0):

For each type of file there will be a specification defining the format.  There may well be headers(information about the data stored in the file) and data structures(ways of organising the actual data in the file), others may just be plain text files where a new line character separates lines.

To write code to interpret a file, for instance .jpg you would need to get the file format specification for JPEG, read it, and then implement it in your code.  You would do this for each file format you needed to read in your program.

Answer (score 0):

The structure and content of common files like images, videos, sound, CAD data, text processing... is extremely complex. Mastering them would take you more than a lifetime.

Files often begin with a signature, i.e. a small number of bytes that is deemed to be unique and can be used to check the file type. But there is no standardization at all. For instance, a MS Bitmap image begins with the letters "BM", while xml content begins with a string like "?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?".

A header is an initial section of the file that gives information about the data itself such as data type and size, allowing the interpret the subsequent data correctly. For instance, the TIFF image format has a complex header that can contain dozens of "tags" before the bitmap data.

Here is an example.

[image]